# Filter double values Report Builder 3.0 ssrs

Tags: filter, double, report, ssrs-2008, builder

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Builder 3.0. I've spent a good 8 hours on this so far and still pretty much at square 1.
My goal is to have a graph that shows an average ''referal delay'' (in days) for each time period.
My problem is that when I have a **identical** file that was referred for 2 different services my graph still compiles the average without discriminating these cases.

For example: 
patient A gets referred to service 1 for which the delay was 10 days and to service 2 for which the delay was 4 days .

Now: the graph does  (Delay N + 10 + 4) / n

I need: (Delay N + 4) / n , i.e. the longest delay of the 2 delays gets ignored.

I've tried using the filters on the dataset, changing the expression in the series group itself, etc. So far unsuccessful. The most I've been able to do, is to make the graph ignore all the cases that have 2 delays, which is definitely not good.

Plus, I thought of using the Min function in this manner below, but it gives me the exact same result that I had initially (all delays are taken into account). So, no good again.

```
=Avg(IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!No_dossier_local.Value)>Count(Fields!No_dossier_local.Value), Min(Fields!Delay.Value), Fields!Delay.Value))
```

Please help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following, first check to see if the count of delays is equal to one, then input that value else input the minimum delay value.

=avg(IIF(Count(Fields!Delay.Value)=1,Fields!Delay.Value,Min(Fields!Delay.Value)))

Comment: Hi Peter! Thanks for the hint, I just tried it, but unfortunately, what it ends up doing is picking the minimal value for the entire period of time, i.e. I have a graph where x is time (years and periods) and where y is the delay in days. So when I try either your code or when I replace [Fields!Delay.Value] by say [Fields!No_dossier_local.Value], it brings up the shortest patient delay for that period regardless the of the other patient delays in that timeframe. But thanks a lot for your help, i'll keep digging in that direction though.

Comment: Just to add some details (in case if it comes up helpful). The original dataset has the following dimensions: year, period (13 periods in a year), clinic location (2 locations), patient number and type of service (physio, ergo, etc.). My desired end-result measure is the delay. I have a measure that I can include as well called Number of references. So say, if I remove the dimension [Type of service] in my dataset, my number of references for a given patient could be higher than 1. However, if I leave [Type of service] in my dataset, the number that number will remain 1.

Comment: Actually, is there a way using Cstr or something to make it understand that if the patient number is identical, take minimal? So, kind of like your suggestion, but instead of Count()? I juste tried =avg(IIF(Fields!No_dossier_local.Value=Fields!No_dossier_local.Value,Fields!Delay.Value,Min(Fields!Delay.Value))), but it gives me the same result as for your expression. ??<(-.-"<)

Comment: Would it be possible to filter the graph by "type of service"? then you would have only one possible delay value? It would then mean having a different graph for each "type of service"

Comment: Hi Peter, that's a good idea and would give a average valid measure of the delay to access one of the services. However, it still won't allow me to see how quickly a patient gets *any* treatment =/